# Davening with a Minyan

Tags: halacha, tefilla, minyan

Would someone explain the requirements to daven (pray) in a minyan, when the minyan is needed and what can't one do absent a minyan? Where can I confirm this? Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12319/5

Answer (score 2):

What you need a minyan for is mentioned in the [Mishnah Megilah 4(3)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9670&st=%d7%9e%d7%92%d7%99%d7%9c%d7%94&pgnum=456); the link is to the Blackman edition with English translation.
The paragraphs in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minyan) entitled "Rituals requiring a minyan" and "Prayer with a minyan" seem to be reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Shulchan Aruch 90:9: Try to daven in shul. If he is "*annus*" and can't make it at least daven "together" with the congregation (at the same time). And if is "*annus*" and couldn't make it on time to the minyan at least daven by himself in the shul.
Mishan Brura (28) explains the power of the davening together with a congregation: Hashem doesn't "*moes*" (dislikes?) the davening of a congregation.

Comment: _Moes_ ≈ "be disgusted with", I think.

Comment: I agree that it sounds better.

Comment: Is this the source in S A for davening with a minyan