# Importance of Minyan

Tags: tefilla, minyan

How far must I go out of my way to pray with a minyan (quorum)? Does it matter if it's longer one direction than the other (ie I have ride back but not there or vice-versa)?

Comment: I can't remember where I saw it so I won't post an answer, but I recall from contemporary sefarim that it is the timing.  So practically I need to delay myself 36 minutes.  If I am taking a bus, the bus stop wait counts as well.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11113/5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One must travel 1 mil (or kilometer) to daven with a minyan, (or 4 mil, if its on his way anyways). I assume that describes the amount of time one must spend travelling rather than the distance. I think we mainly look at the time to travel there,* but probably both are a factor. See Shulchan Aruch [OHC #90](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A6):

**סעיף ט**
ישתדל אדם להתפלל בבית הכנסת עם הצבור ואם הוא אנוס שאינו יכול לבוא לבית הכנסת יכוין להתפלל בשעה שהצבור מתפללים (והוא הדין בני אדם הדרים בישובים ואין להם מנין מכל מקום יתפללו שחרית וערבית בזמן שהצבור מתפללים. סמ"ג). וכן אם נאנס ולא התפלל בשעה שהתפללו הצבור והוא מתפלל ביחיד אף על פי כן יתפלל בבית הכנסת:

**סעיף יא**
מי שיש לו בית הכנסת בעירו ואינו נכנס בו להתפלל נקרא שכן רע וגורם גלות לו ולבניו:

**סעיף טז**
ההולך בדרך והגיע לעיר ורוצה ללון בה אם לפניו עד ד' מילין מקום שמתפללים בי' צריך לילך שם ולאחריו צריך לחזור עד מיל כדי להתפלל בי':

Comment: That doesn't really explain how to deal with the return travel time being longer than a mil but approaching travel time being less than a mil. Do we say a sum total of 36 minutes (2 mil)?

Comment: That makes sense but I don't have any proof for it. The sources seem to mainly discuss the distance to travel there, perhaps due to them always being equal.

Comment: Though I think the halacha might only be that one needs to go one mil off his route, even if to get back is less than a mil (say by travelling diagonally). See MB there.

Comment: I dont see how you arrive at *one must* from ישתדל אדם.

Answer (score 1):

Yalkut Yosef I think says- 1 mil