# Seeking sources about the necessity for finding a מנין

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, minyan, priorities

I am looking for sources about the necessity for finding a מנין.  More specifically, whether or not one has to always be in close range of a מנין, or if he can intentionally put himself in a position in which he cannot get to one.

Comment: Is this a question?

Answer (score 4):

The sefer meishiv nivonim OC siman 13 answers a question about if one could go to kivrei tzadikkim in poland if one knows there won't be a minyan there. He comes out one should not do it but he gets there with many mekors for it. Some sources: Tur siman 89,Minchas Yitzchak 7 siman 6,Igros Moshe OC 2:27,Shulchan Aruch Harav siman 17, Eretz Tzvi siman 22,Yad Eliyahu siman 6,Maharil siman 118,there are more in the sefer.

Answer (score 2):

A Google search (for "[davening with a minyan](https://www.google.com/search?q=davening+with+a+minyan)") turns up:

- [TEFILLAH B' TZIBUR: HOW IMPORTANT?](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5759/vayeira.html) - From the OU
- [Davening with a Minyan](http://www.ou.org/publications/ja/5765/5765fall/LEGALEAS.PDF) - From torah.org
- [To Daven alone or with a Minyan?](http://koshertorah.com/PDF/Daven-alone.pdf) - from koshertorah.com

...and many other excellent sources (including [our very own!](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12319/883)), which in turn bring lots of their own sources.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to look up sources about the more general question of putting oneself in a position where one is unable to do a mitzvah. This is relevant, among others, to the question of being "on a distant journey" and therefore unable to offer the korban Pesach; see Minchas Chinuch 5 and a great deal of commentary on that. (There is in fact a booklet on Hebrewbooks - חיוב מצוות הזמניות קודם זמן המצוה - that discusses many different issues and sub-issues in this regard.)