# If there are not the required ten in a minyan?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, minyan

How should one proceed if after arriving there are not the required ten for a minyan for let's say Shacharit or Mincha?

Comment: Are you asking what stuff gets skipped, or about strategies for delaying or drumming up a minyan, or about leniencies in counting, or something else?

Comment: One should proceed to the next shul

Comment: Very rarely, on shabbos morning, we have not had a minyan when starting pezuka dezimra (I am usually leading).  On our rabbi's instruction, we go ahead and start.  If we don't have a minyan when we reach the first two kaddishes, we skip them and press on.  On those rare occasions, we will have gotten a minyan shortly thereafter.  I have no source for this, only our practice at my shul.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/organized-prayer-in-the-synagogue-with-less-than-10-people-community-or-not

Comment: Do the answers at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11113/ and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9797 answer your question, Nun50? If not, can you [edit] your question to clarify what you're looking for that isn't on either of those pages?

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of practice at the daily minyon at the military post where I worked, we would have to continue davening individually until Yishtabach and usually we would get a minyon by Borchu. If a minyon does not come, then we have to daven the rest individually and do not say Borchu, Chazoras Hashatz, read the Torah, or say kadish. We do all daven together so that we stay at the same place, so that if a tenth person comes, we can continue with the minyon.

At the mincha minyon, everyone would daven individually because we would have to get back to work and could not wait.