# What is considered praying with a minyan?

Tags: tefilla, minyan, tefillah-betzibbur

What is the minium that one must say with a minyan to count as if he prayed with a minyan?

Since "tefillah" when mentioned in the Talmud referrs to the Amidah is it safe to assume that only praying the Amidah with a minyan is what's necessary to count as if you prayed with a minyan? Or, is the shema and/or pesukei dizimra also included?

Practical difference: when you come late to synagogue and need to catch up - does saying shema and pesukei with or without the congregation make a difference?

Comment: Related (dupe?): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11113/5323

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  Tefillah with a minyan refers specifically to the Amidah.  Of course, there are many other benefits of praying everything with a minyan, being able to answer Amen and respond to Kaddish.